# psutil - suspending process

Tags: python, linux

I'm writing a script in Python for Linux that should suspend process when given conditions are met and later resume it. To do so I'm using psutil (http://code.google.com/p/psutil).
The problem I encountered is rather strange. When I use python command line, everything works fine - process is suspended and later resumed. However, when I use the same function in a script file and then I try to run it, it throws exception:

```
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'suspend'
```

Snippet of code:

```
p = psutil.Process(19931)
p.suspend()
print 'suspended'
time.sleep(10)
p.resume()
print 'resumed'
```

Of course 19931 is typed PID of the process I've started in background and want it to be suspended.

Does anyone have some ideas or hints? Psutil is the newest version installed from Google code.

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old entry but for the ones who encountered this problem recently,

this code works fine for me (Python 3.7.3) :

```
psutil.Process(pid=19931).suspend()
```

And similarly

```
psutil.Process(pid=19931).resume()
```

But you have to be sure that referred process is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would suspect when Python behaves differently under the interactive shell and executing a script would be running different versions of Python. This can easily happen when you point to an interpreter in your script file with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

This is a long shot since, according to the psutil website, it's supposed to work well with Python versions from 2.4 to 3.3. Also, your snippet works fine on my machine (kernel 2.6.32, Python 2.6.6).